# Android - Send HTTP Request (API > 23)

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need something that "download" the webpage content...I mean, I need to have the HTTP Response and store it into a String var.

For example If i insert [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the response will look like: `<html><head></head><body>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE etc etc etc...<><><>`

I tried some codes I saw, but they are from API < 23, and Android have removed HTTP APACHE.

THank you in advance

Comment: You might want to consider using Retrofit.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpUrlConnection is the replacement for the apache libraries.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Yes it does.  He said the Apache libraries were removed in v23, so they can't be used.  He was correct.  I told him what API replaced them.

Comment: It was exactly  what I was looking for... thank you Gabe!

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in gradle file and you can use HTTP Apache classes in API 23 +.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:
1- use Android URLConnection for EX:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   try {
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     in.close();
   }
 }
```

2- add the following to your gradle file

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use the OKHttp library.

Add this to your gradle file:

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

The library is relatively simple to use:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String body = response.body().string();
```